# LibreOffice Calc equivalent to Excel "Evaluate Formula" feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

Excel has an "Evaluate Formula" feature (it's located in the Excel Formulas ribbon among the Formula Auditing group, as shown in the picture below).

[image: Excel's "Evaluate Formula" feature]

Is there an equivalent to that Excel feature in LibreOffice Calc?

**EDIT:**

Following fixer1234 suggestion, I add a link to a site showing [an example of how the Excel "Evaluate Formula" feature works](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EUZ139/QT620212321.htm). This way, users familiar with Calc but less familiar with Excel, may better understand what the matter is about and more easily contribute information.

In the example you can notice what I call the step-by-step "*evolution*" of the formula. In fact, with every step of the evaluation process, part of the formula is replaced with its actual result till the reaching of the final result. (This may come very handy when dealing with particularly long formulas.)

Comment: For clarification, I had previously added a reference to a different feature, which I took back out since that wasn't what you were referring to.  For people not familiar with this feature, can you add a sentence or two to the question describing what it does?  Users familiar with Calc but less familiar with Excel, might have information to contribute if they understand the nature of the feature.

Answer (score 6):

I'm answering my own question with what I know so far, anyone who can provide better solutions/news about new Calc features, really welcome!

---

As far as I know, what comes closest in Calc to Excel "Evaluate Formula" is the "Formula Wizard" (you can open it by selecting the cell containing the formula you want to check out and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or by clicking on the "fx" icon in the formula bar).

It's not that bad at all **but** it's not exactly the same thing yet; in fact the process differs in the way you don't view the same Excel's step by step "*evolution*" of the formula but a step by step "evaluation" of it.

P.S.:
For completeness about the matter I'll add that what works the same way in either Excel and in Calc, instead, is the partial evaluation of a formula that can be done by selecting a portion of a formula in the formula bar and hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> (in this case, you'll obtain the calculated result only for the highlighted section of the formula).

Comment: +1 for your PS.  Wasn't aware of that feature and it is useful.

Comment: Share the knowledge! :-) P.S. (yes, another one here, I abuse of them... and love parentheses as much too) with Mac the keys combination should be `Fn + F9`